# Count duplicate numbers in postgres

Tags: count, postgresql-9.1

i have quick question.

I would like to count rows with same number.
This is what i get:

[image]

So i have 4 rows, with same number(59 b) and in `count column` i get ones.
I need to get `4` instead of `1`, becouse i have 4 rows with same number.

This is my `sql`:

```
SELECT (z.miasto ||' '|| z.ulica ||' '|| z.nr_dom) as adres, (z.sym ||z.sym_ul||' '|| z.nr_dom) as symbol, zd.status, zd.id_administrator, z.uwagi,
COUNT(*) as liczba_osob
FROM zgloszenia as z
LEFT JOIN zgl_dzialamy AS zd ON (z.sym ||z.sym_ul||' '|| z.nr_dom) = (zd.sym ||zd.sym_ul||' '|| zd.nr_budynku)
WHERE status < 5
group by adres, symbol, zd.id_administrator, z.uwagi, zd.status
```

Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why COUNT doesnt work is because the grouped values cannot aggregate. 
They appear to be distinct from each other (probably the blacked out value: z.uwagi).

What you can do is SELECTing the non-DISTINCT values together and COUNT those instead. You can join this VALUE to your table after once the COUNTing is done. Or you can aggregate this column to your table as an array or json object.

```
SELECT 
  (z.miasto ||' '|| z.ulica ||' '|| z.nr_dom) as adres,
  (z.sym ||z.sym_ul||' '|| z.nr_dom) as symbol,
  zd.status,
  zd.id_administrator,
  -- z.uwagi, -- VALUE IS DISTINCT
  COUNT(*) as liczba_osob
  FROM zgloszenia as z
    LEFT JOIN zgl_dzialamy AS zd ON (z.sym ||z.sym_ul||' '|| z.nr_dom) = (zd.sym ||zd.sym_ul||' '|| zd.nr_budynku)
  WHERE status < 5
  group by
    adres,
    symbol,
    zd.id_administrator,
    -- z.uwagi,
    zd.status
```